# How can I get credit card transaction work at medium trust level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorize.net

I have a hosting providor -hostgator--that only allows a medium trust level. I could only get a credit card transaction to process at a full trust level from my environment. How can I get it to work at medium trust level on the host?

Thx

-using the following sample code from authorize: https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-csharp/blob/master/PaymentTransactions/ChargeCreditCard.cs

Either get one of these two errors:

Security Exception

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file.

Comment: Have you contacted your host?

Comment: many times, they give me the run around for the most part and say I have to change my settings to medium trust.

Comment: From the error message, you need to run it on full trust permission. If they don't support full trust hosting, then you need to find other hosting provider that offer full trust.